# Tensorflow skflow, Data seems compatible, Valuerror, Shape error

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

Trying to run a very simple nn classifier with skflow.

```
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(
hidden_units=[10, 10, 10],
n_classes=10,
batch_size=100,
learning_rate=0.05)
print (data.train.images).shape
print (data.train.labels).shape
classifier.fit(data.train.images,data.train.labels)
```

output is :
(73257, 3072)
(73257, 10)

and the error is :

```
in assert_same_rank
    "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, 10) and (?, 10, 10) must have the same rank
```

I do not really understand what the problem is here :(

Comment: what versions of tensorflow and skflow are you using?

Comment: tensorflow 0.71 and skflow 0.10

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the labels of your dataset are one-hot vectors. (In this case, I use mnist dataset. See also https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html)

```
In [1]: from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

In [2]: mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_DATA/", one_hot=True)
Extracting MNIST_DATA/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

In [3]: mnist.train.labels
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  1.,  0.]])

In [4]: mnist.train.labels.shape
Out[4]: (55000, 10)

In [5]: import skflow

In [6]: classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 10, 10], n_classes=10, batch_size=100, learning_rate=0.05)

In [7]: classifier.fit(mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels)
```

Then I got same error.

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 10) and (?, 10, 10) must have the same rank
```

But skflow assumes that lables are numbers between 0 and 9. (one_hot=False)

```
In [5]: mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_DATA/", one_hot=False)
Extracting MNIST_DATA/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_DATA/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

In [6]: mnist.train.labels
Out[6]: array([7, 3, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=uint8)

In [7]: classifier.fit(mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels)
Step #99, avg. train loss: 2.31658
Step #199, avg. train loss: 1.63361
Out[7]: 
TensorFlowDNNClassifier(batch_size=100, class_weight=None,
            config_addon=<skflow.addons.config_addon.ConfigAddon object at 0x11cf7eb90>,
            continue_training=False, hidden_units=[10, 10, 10],
            keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=10000, learning_rate=0.05,
            max_to_keep=5, n_classes=10, optimizer='SGD', steps=200,
            tf_master='', tf_random_seed=42, verbose=1)
```

Please give it a try.

Comment: It might that you are right, but right now, how can i test it ? my data is one_hot encoded, how can i tell skflow that thats the case?

Comment: I think it would be better to convert data fomat previously. For example,  `labels_dense = [np.nonzero(mnist.train.labels[i])[0][0] for i in range(len(mnist.train.labels))]` (It's not an smart code)